# Activity Transitions fade-in

Tags: android, animation, transition

For my app, I plan to have a grid of images and when you select one the image increases in size and the rest of the images get grayed out. I read  about Activity Transitions but have never implemented that before so I'm not sure if this is the appropriate way of achieving the correct affect. I was thinking of possibly using a fragment and an animation to display the image in a larger size but how do I display the activity in the background with a grey tint to it so that it looks out of focus? I'm looking here to see what you think the most appropriate method of making this work. Here is a gif of exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: It's quite a lot of code for that, to put in a full "pretty" answer, but on this video, the guy goes through the main points of doing this type of animation/transition. On the video refers to it as the "retrocompatible" method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLhA0I00TnI

Comment: On a second note, I'm pretty would be possible on the "lollipop+" method, but for something like you show, I wouldn't use that method.

Comment: Not an answer to my question but this is a very detailed blog on creating your own [Transition Animations](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html).